# No JS experience --Bokeh Simple JSCallback to update graph with Select values

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm trying to run a standalone Bokeh HTML file with a callback based on the value in a drop down menu. This means I can't use the following because it only works in bokeh server:

```
dropdown = Select(title ='Term Dropdown', value='Fall 2018', options = Terms)
def update_plot(attr, old, new):
    # Set the yr name to slider.value and new_data to source.data
    term = dropdown.value
    new_data = {
        'x'       : df.loc[term].Grade,
        'y'       : df.loc[term].grade_count
    }
    source.data = new_data


dropdown.on_change('value', update_plot)
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out the callback or where I am going wrong with it.

I've looked at all of the similar questions here but the data is not the same as mine. 
Here is an example DataFrame that Matches my data frame:

```
data_test = {'Term': ['Fall 2018', 'Fall 2018', 'Fall 2018', 'Fall 2018',  'Spring 2018',  'Spring 2018',  'Spring 2018',  'Spring 2018', 'Fall 2017','Fall 2017','Fall 2017','Fall 2017'], 
        'Grade': ['A+','A','B','C','A+','A','B','C','A+','A','B','C'],
        'grade_count': [4500, 500, 6000, 250, 103, 1345, 2503, 324, 684,230, 566,2344]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data_test)  

df.set_index(['Term'], inplace=True)
```

Here are my two CDS's:

```
source = ColumnDataSource(data={
        'x' : df.Grade,
        'y' : df.grade_count
        })

true_source = ColumnDataSource(data={
        'x' : []
        'y' : []
        })
```

This is the graph object:

```
p1.vbar(x='x', top='y', width=.75, bottom=0, source=source, line_color=grade_cmap, fill_color=grade_cmap)
```

[image]

Here is the callback that I've tried to make:

```
 callback=CustomJS(args=dict(source=source, ts=true_source), code=""""
                    var data1=ts.data;

                    var a=data1['x']
                    var b=data1['y']

                    var data=source.data;
                    var f=cb_obj.value;

                    var x=[];
                    var y=[];


                    for(var i=0;i<a.length; i++){
                        if(x[i]==f){
                          x.push(a[i]);
                          y.push(b[i]);

                        }
                    }
                    data1['x']=x;
                    data1['y']=y;
                    source.change.emit();
            """)

dropdown = Select(title ='Term Dropdown', value='Fall 2018', options = Terms)
dropdown.js_on_change('value', callback)
```

I just want the term information to update when I choose the same term in the dropdown.

Comment: I think my issue is that I'm not actually updating the X and Y values...I'm only updating the .loc filter value.

Comment: I think I need to do something like x.push(source.data[cb_obj.value]) but I don't know how do a slice like that in javascript.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Alright I finally figured it out with the help of my friend (for the JS part).

I'm posting the answer in the hope of helping others.

Make original source full dataframe and make true source an empty datasource.

```
source = ColumnDataSource(df)

true_source = ColumnDataSource(data={
        'x' : [],
        'y' : []

        })
```

Make Source true_source (empty source)

```
p1.vbar(x='x', top='y', width=.75, bottom=0, source=true_source, line_color=grade_cmap, fill_color=grade_cmap)
```

make the JS callback:

```
callback=CustomJS(args=dict(source=source, ts=true_source), code="""
                    const ts_data = ts.data;
                    const source_data = source.data;
                    const dropdown_value = cb_obj.value;
                    const x1 = [];
                    const y1 = [];
                    const terms = source_data.Term;

                    terms.forEach((term, index) => {
                          if (term === dropdown_value) {
                            x1.push(source_data.Grade[index]);
                            y1.push(source_data.grade_count[index]);
                          }
                        });
                    ts_data.x=x1;
                    ts_data.y=y1;
                    ts.change.emit();
            """)
dropdown = Select(title ='Term Dropdown', value='Fall 2018', options = Terms)
dropdown.js_on_change('value', callback)
```

Comment: Have a self-contained complete example (including import statements etc. ) would be more helpful for others who want to replicate this example.